# I'm facing a problem with using pdfviewer library to handle links in the PDF

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdfview, androidpdfviewer

I want to handle links in my pdf but .linkHandler method is not working and giving me errors that it should be renamed but according to library, I'm using this correctly.

Have a look at the code

```
   PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("YEK.pdf")
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                        // PDF loaded successfully
                    }
                })
                .load();

        pdfView.fromAsset("YEK.pdf")
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                        // PDF loaded successfully
                    }
                })
                .onPageChange(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
                        // Page changed
                    }
                })
                .onPageError(new OnPageErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageError(int page, Throwable t) {
                        // Error occurred while loading page
                    }
                })
                .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight) {
                        // PDF rendered successfully
                        pdfView.enableAnnotationRendering(true);
                        pdfView.linkHandler(new DefaultLinkHandler(pdfView));
                    }
                })
                .load();



    }
}
```

I am using to write a pdfreader app. And the pdf which I'm using in the app has embedded links. I want to handle that links but this is not working. Android studio is the IDE 'm using.

Here is the implementation for the library in *build.gradle*

`implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'`